# Getting layer list back in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I closed a side panel I had, where I had a list of layers and which I used to switch on and off layers, and I cannot find how to get it back. I have tried all the buttons I could think of, but I cannot see it again.

Can someone help?

Comment: View > Panels and tick "Layers" worked for me

Answer (score 11):

View -> Panels and tick 'Layers'. :)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this but it did not work. I had to close the programme and reopen it, and now it works. Thanks again

Comment: It would be good to note any default keyboard shortcut here too (I'm currently failing to find one)